# Ubuntu randomly slows to a crawl for no reason

Tags: 11.10, performance, cpu

This is a VERY strange problem. My installation of 11.10 will randomly slow to a crawl, giving the feeling of either max CPU/MEM useage, when they are both at normal levels.

Although there seems to be no pattern, it will happen when I am away from the computer for a while, but it will sometimes happen when I'm watching a long movie or something. It is VERY annoying, since the only way I can get rid of it's slow performance is to log out, but sometimes even the log in screen feels laggy. 
PLEASE help, thank you very much!

Comment: The problem is definitely ***not*** due to some kind of search indexing. I have the same problem and many others also report it for various versions of Ubuntu and Mint running various hardware. The same install (***literally*** the same, i.e., move the SSD to different hardware) runs fine on other hardware. I'm running on an ASUS Chromebox without Crouton (i.e., Ubuntu is ***the*** OS, not a guest OS.) Same problem whether 14.10 32-bit or 64-bit. (I tried installing 14.04 but Ubuntu versions from around 12.04-14.04 have problems shutting down on certain hardware, including the standard PC hard

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like indexing for a search engine. You can take a look at your disk usage with `iotop`. Maybe there is something like stigi, nepomuk or zeitgeist going crazy.